Old Reverse Osmosis system feeding two fridges and an ice maker via copper lines. Anyway to improve the situation?
So I had to renovate the kitchen and some of the plumbing. But the plumber failed to note that I have an OLD Culligan RO system feeding the lines to the two fridges and ice maker and he put 1/4" copper runs to all these areas. Culligan says they can upgrade the system to a new RO that has a "remineralized" calcium filter that apparently leaches mainly calcium back into the "finished" water to reduce the corrosive effect of "pure RO" water. Is there an alternative RO system other than Culligan that you can more safely use with Copper? Or a different filtration system that would feed three areas more safely?

It sounds like your question is about the use of copper plumbing with an RO system. Please revise your title to reflect that.

If I'm reading these pipes correctly from the tiny photo, you also have some sort of whole-house filter.
Remineralization filters are usually optional and they have to go on the output side of the system.  So if it's integral to the system, then just look at a better deal that doesn't make you pay for it.
Another drawback is that the water can develop a very strong odor and flavor if the water sits in a remineralization stage for too long.  It's a very imperfect technology.

so the question then is it worth trying to make this RO system be compatible with copper piping or should I abandon that options in favor of less "complete" filtration system...

I added a post RO mixing valve. I know it means I have SOME contaminants in my outgoing water but also minerals and improved TDS. Closer to 90 now. I think that should be enough to prevent leaching of the copper.
